Replace DF input column value from dictionary in pyspark
I have a dataframe like df_1
+------+-------------+----------+-----+
|KPI_ID|      FORMULA|PARAMETERS|VALUE|
+------+-------------+----------+-----+
|   132|131 * (1-133)|   131,133| null|
|   135|   134 * 1000|       134| null|
|   138|    137 - 139|   137,139| null|
|   143|    142 * 137|   142,137| null|
+------+-------------+----------+-----+

dictionary as kpi_values:
{'123': 'None', '124': '763.675293', '125': '1249.6796875', '126': '9313.3896484', '127': '14742.0',
 '128': 'None', '129': '2.8590682', '130': '6010.1899414', '131': '2.96', '133': '83.3741302', '134': '-1.0', '136': '955.4359741', '137': '27989.8808594', '139': '1674.25', '140': '97000.0',
 '141': '2388.3144531', '142': '0.0', '144': '7421.25', '145': '0.0', '146': '1.3425742'}

in the output dataframe I need the DF to be :
+------+-------------+----------+-----+-------------------------+
|KPI_ID|      FORMULA|PARAMETERS|VALUE|FORMULAREPLACED         |
+------+-------------+----------+-----+-------------------------+
|   132|131 * (1-133)|   131,133| null|  2.96 * (1-83.3741302)  |
|   135|   134 * 1000|       134| null|  -1.0 * 1000            |
|   138|    137 - 139|   137,139| null|  27989.8808594 - 1674.25|
|   143|    142 * 137|   142,137| null|  0.0 * 27989.8808594    |
+------+-------------+----------+-----+-------------------------+

I have tried below options:
for kpi_id, value in kpi_values.items():
    placeholder = f"{kpi_id}"
    if value is None:
        value = '0'
    else:
       value      # Handle NULL values
    df_1 = df_1.withColumn("FORMULAREPLACED",F.expr(f"regexp_replace(FORMULA,'{placeholder }','{value}')"))
df_1 = df_1.withColumn("FORMULA", F.expr(f"replace(FORMULA, '{placeholder }', '{value}')"))
df_1=df_1.replace(list(kpi_values.keys()), list(kpi_values.values()), 'FORMULA')

The above code is not giving the required output.
I cannot create UDF because it is not supported by unity catalog, I am not able to pass the column from DF it often says col not callable

I would suggest you load the dictionary as a DataFrame (with keys & values as columns) and then join it to your DataFrame:
df_kpi_values = (
    spark.createDataFrame(kpi_values.items())
    .withColumnRenamed("_1", "KPI_ID")
    .withColumnRenamed("_2", "FORMULA_REPLACEMENT_VALUE")
)

df_result = (
     df_1
     .join(df_kpi_values , ["KPI_ID"], "left")
 )

In general it is always good to think only in the two central types of Spark - columns and dataframes. Most problems can be solved by staying within these types and by keeping to the built-in functionality of the DataFrame API.
As soon as you mix it with Python types / have to use F.expr you inevitably end up with a less than elegant solution in my experience (sometimes necessary, but never fun).

df_result = (
df_1
.join(df_kpi_values , ["KPI_ID"], "left")
) this is not working as we do not have the KPI_ID from df_kpi_values in df_1. want to replace in this string 131 with 2.96 in this case and 133 with 83.3741302. how to get this

What do you mean you do not have the KPI_ID in df_1? Your literally wrote "I have a dataframe like df_1" and then listed "KPI_ID" directly as the first column :D
